Converting point shapefile into polygon in QGIS
I have a point shapefile in QGIS 3.26. It is made of many points, and many overlap with each other. I need to make a polygon shapefile out of these points so that those points that overlap or are close to each other get merged into one polygon. I also need the border area of these points in a polygon format.
Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

The buffer tool window:


DB-Scan cluster first, then create convex hulls based on the cluster Ids.

Consider posting this as an answer

Thanks @Erik. Could you please explain a bit how I can do this step?


Buffer the points with a positive distance, I use 50 m. Set Dissolve result=Yes and Keep disjoint results separate=Yes
Buffer the buffer layer from step 1 with the same but negative distance -50, to create the green polygon layer:



Thanks. I add a screenshot of the buffer window of my question. It does not have the 'Keep disjoint results separate' option and for 'Dissolve result', I selected it.

I guess you have another QGIS version, I have the option here. If you end up with one large multipart polygon, split it with Multipart to singleparts

Why do I have to create two buffers? one with a negative distance value? I set my distance as 1m and it is already big. Considering areas outside the points that it should not.

Thats why you buffer the first buffer output with a negative distance, to remove the parts outside the points. You should not buffer the points twice
